# How to call webapi controller in class library project from webapi project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi project and a class library project which has got the webapi controller.

I have inherited from ApiController and make sure both the webapi project and class library project contains same webapi assemblies.i.e

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Though i have added System.web.http assembly to class library project, 
when i add the [RoutePrefix"")] attribute to the controller in class library project, i am getting "The type or namespace name 'RoutePrefix' could not be found.."

Can anyone help how to make this work so i can make the endpoint work?

Thanks

Comment: try including a reference to `System.Web.Http` this is where the `RoutePrefixAttribute` is defined.

Comment: Yes, I have already added

Comment: Just to be safe; do you have using statement at the top of your source for the correct namespace? Or fully qualified the attribute?

Comment: I am able to add the RoutePrefix attribute after uninstall all the packages and install the Microsoft.WebApi.Core 5.2.3 package. But the endpoint is not working.

Answer (score 0):

i) It worked finally after i deleted the existing nuget packages and installed the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3 from Package Manager Console. The problem i guess is the system.web.http version was pointing to 4.0.0 instead of 5.2.3

ii) Now able to add RoutePrefix attribute to the webapi controller in class library project

iii) endpoints are working fine